# A Regex to match any sentence but avoiding character repetition

Tags: regex

I am looking for help to create a Regex to validates a string that satisfies these 4 criteria:

1. The string must contain white space.
2. The string must end with a full-stop/period.
3. The string must have a minimum of 15 characters.
4. The string **must not** contain a repetition of 3 or more characters. *This is part I'm particularly struggling with.*

For example:

**Pass**

- One two three four.

**Fail**

- OOOne two thee four.
- One two thee fffour.
- One two three four
- One two three.
- Onetwothreefour.

If possible could you explain how the regex is constructed to give me a better idea of how to construct them in future?

---

Here is what I've tried so far,

```
^(.*?={15,})(\.\Z)$
```

but I fear its not even close, please help.

Comment: Why must this be done with a regular expression? Except for #4, the rest are really easy to do with normal string commands.

Comment: @BryanOakley, what do you mean by "normal string commands"?

Comment: @Jodrell: I mean you can easily get the length of a string with a function, you can also quickly check to see if there are spaces with a function, and you can quickly check whether the last character is a period. Since you didn't specify, I'm assuming you're using some sort of programming language.

Comment: This `^(.*?={15,})(\.\Z)$` is a pretty poor attempt at a regex. Can you break down the parts to that and explain it a bit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=\S*\s)(?!.*?(.)\1{2}).{14,}\.$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP1kU2/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?=\S*\s)` - Lookahead to make sure there is at least one whitespace
- `(?!.*?(.)\1{2})` - Negative Lookahead to make sure there is no case of 3 consecutive characters
- `.{14,}` to make sure there are at least 14 characters (15th being the last dot)
- `\.$` to make sure dot is always the last character

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @anubhava this will help me to understand the composition of Regexes more.